# How to pass metadatas using Stripe.createPaymentMethod()?

Tags: stripe-payments

With the JS library Stripe V3, I collect payment informations using the method `stripe.createPaymentMethod()`. I'm trying to pass metadatas through it.

According to the docs (https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-create-payment-method), the last argument of the method can be an object containing the billing details and metadatas. Therefore, it is required to use the keys "billing_details" and "metadata" in this object (https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create).

The billing details appear in the Stripe dashboard, once the payment is validated, but not the metadatas.

The metadatas must be a "set of key-value pairs that you can attach to an object.", so I don't see what is wrong my code:

```
stripe.createPaymentMethod('card', cardNumber, {
 billing_details: {
  "address": {
    [...]
  },
  "email": 'XXX',
  "name": 'XXX',
  "phone": 'XXX'
 },
 metadata: {
  "numero": 'XXX' ,
  "affectation": "XXX"
 }
}).then(function(result) { 
 [...] 
})
```

I managed to do it on back-end with the method `\Stripe\PaymentIntent::create()`, so it is even weirder that it doesn't work on front-end! See code below:

```
$intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
      'payment_method' => $payment_method_id,
      'amount' => $payment_amount * 100,
      'currency' => 'eur',
      'confirmation_method' => 'manual',
      'confirm' => true,
      'description' => $payment_desc,
      'metadata' => [
        'affectation' => $payment_project,
        'numero' => $payment_phone
      ]
    ]);
```

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried attaching the metadata as a flat object, next to billing_address, email, phone ?
The back-end `paymentIntent.create()` is not related to the client-side method `createPaymentMethod `

Comment: (sorry for late reply) After searches, the method `\Stripe\PaymentIntent` can only receive already existing keys in metadatas, such as `order_id` https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/update#update_payment_intent-metadata